# Best way to run unison with rclone: several configs in parallel or all in one?

Tags: synchronization, unison, rclone

I'm using `rclone` to mount my cloud (Proton Drive, new arrival) on openSUSE Tumbleweed. I want to sync my local files with the mounted files via `unison`.

I've never used `unison` before, so I have two big questions:

1. I have a lot (close to a million I think) of files in one of my folders, and an uneven distribution throughout the others. So: should I run multiple instances of `unison` in parallel, each taking care of one of the folders, or should I have one `unison`
   `big_config.prf` file with all the folders in question listed inside? Given that the monster folder doesn't require much syncing, but the smaller ones do.
2. What's the best way of keeping unison running between suspend, sleep and hibernate events? I've thought of a `systemd` unit but I'm really bad at using that, so if you see any other option...

That's all, thanks for your help. And I ❤️ Unison for all the testing I did it works great!

Thanks again.

Comment: (1) I think Unison won't be bothered by the quantity or distribution of your files; just run one instance. (2) This is a goode question. The canonical way to do this is to use Unison's built-in `repeat=watch` option, however [that will lead to issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/709319/427334). You could use `systemd` or `cron` or any system scheduling tool instead. I'm simply got a shell script with a `while true; do` loop that runs at startup and calls Unison every 5 minutes.